# Wildcard to match `path` and `serviceName` in Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster with an undefined series of services, and what I want to do is serve each service on an endpoint, with the ability to add new services at any time, with them still being available at an endpoint.

I'm looking for a way to set, in my ingress, a wildcard on `serviceName`, so that `/xx` will be routed to service `xx`, `/yy` to service `yy`, etc.
Another solution that I could also use would be matching `http://xx.myurl.com` to service `xx`.

Is this something doable with Kubernetes?

I imagine something of the like

```yaml
- path: /(.*)
  backend:
    serviceName: $1
    servicePort: 80
```

Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something the Ingress system supports. Some other tools may, you can do this pretty easily with a static Nginx config for example.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I had in mind too, thanks for confirming that :)

Comment: Any Direction on how to achieve that? even with static Nginx config, @coderanger?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with ingress, here are both solutions:

for `my-domain.com/xxx`

in ingress service you do something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  labels:
      name: ingress-service
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /xx/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: xx
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /yy/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: yy
            port:
              number: 80
```

so everything that is pointed to `my-domain.com/xx` will be pointed out to `xx` service and it will remove `/xx/` from the path, ex:
If you make a request to `my-domain.com/xx/values`, the request will be forwarded as `my-domain.com/values` to the `xx` service.

Learn more about it at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

As well as you can see here how the paths work: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples

The other solution for `xx.my-domain.com` you can do it like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  labels:
      name: ingress-service
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xx.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: xx
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: yy.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: yy
            port:
              number: 80
```

You can learn more about it at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not exactly what I am looking for: I want the service name to be guessed from the endpoint. In other words, I want to say " endpoint `(*)` will redirect to service `$1` ", so I don't want to have to define the service names myself. I'll have N services, that should all be available on one endpoint with the same name, so I don't want to have to specify the couple endpoint / service name every time (1/2)

Comment: I do this right now outside of kube with a proxy that takes the URL (`url.com/endpoint`) and redirect the traffic to service `endpoint`, and after the proxy launch, if ever I add a new service foo, it is available at `url.com/foo` without modifying my proxy file. (2/2)

Comment: @ColinFAY oh i see, then it is my bad. I misunderstood the question :) But yeah, then that would make sense.